# Using a constant in another constant during initialization

Tags: php

I have following class:

```
class RemoteService {

    const BASE_URL = "...";
    const SEARCH_URL = self::BASE_URL . "search";

    const MIN_PAGE_SIZE = 0;
    const MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 100;

    const ERROR_INVALID_PAGE_SIZE = sprintf('page size must be between %d and %d', self::MIN_PAGE_SIZE, self::MAX_PAGE_SIZE);

    ...
}
```

I can use `BASE_URL` while initializing `SEARCH_URL`. However, I cannot use `MIN_PAGE_SIZE` and `MAX_PAGE_SIZE` in `sprintf()` to initialize `ERROR_INVALID_PAGE_SIZE` and get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operation
```

What is the reason for this? Is concatenation as in first part only way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use concatenation. The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) says:

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a **function call**.

So you can't call `sprintf()`.